# Is there any way with which we can print the following pattern?

Tags: java

```
    class pattern
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            int i,j,p=1;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=i; j++)
                {
                   System.out.print(p+" ");
                   p=p+2;
                }
                if(i>=2)
                p=p-2;
               System.out.println ();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the below written output

```
1
3 5
5 7 9
7 9 11 13
9 11 13 15 17
```

but the output obtained by the above written code is given below

```
1
3 5 
5 7 9
9 11 13 15 
15 17 19 21 23
```

I want last digit of second row to be displayed at the starting of third row and last two digits of third row to be displayed in the beginning of the fourth row and so on.

Comment: @AntoineB all the  questions are not homework i think this site is meant for clarification and answer to our questions rather than useless comments,

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your issue is that you're trying to keep of the wrong things, namely the number being printed. Instead, keep track of the current line and current item in the line you're currently at.

1. loop through all lines
2. for each line: determine a) starting number b) how many items you need to print
3. loop starting at the starting number and print the items you need to print

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, 5)
       .mapToObj(line -> IntStream.range(0, line+1)
           .map(i -> (line*2+1) + (2 * i))
           .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

Comment: you correct the code if possible according to the output required that has been mentioned above first pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = 5;
for(int start = 1; start < length*2; start += 2){
  for(int j = start;j < start*2; j += 2)
    System.out.print(j + " ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

As AntoineB said StackOverflow is not a site to do homeworks, you should at least tried to solve the problem by yourself, if there are parts that you don't understand then reach help. don't expect others to do your home works

Comment: He provided the code he wrote, that is enough of an attempt I think.

Answer (score 0):

Note the pattern of the first number in each row:

```
row 0 -> 1
row 1 -> 3
row 2 -> 5
row 3 -> 7
row 4 -> 9
```

This is `row*2 + 1`

So you need to loop for each row and calculate that first number. Then you add 2 to it for every column.

```
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    int value = 2*row + 1;

    for(int col=0; col <= row; col++) {
        System.out.print(value+" ");
        value = value+2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```